# Flickering black screen after kb2919355 (Windows 8.1 Update 1) - no OS access - no safe mode - can't system restore

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-update, system-restore, black-screen-of-death

I can't believe I'm going through this again. I recently updated my windows 8.1 with kb2919355 and my PC doesn't boot anymore. I'm getting a black flickering logon screen where it's impossible to login (Same issue in safe mode). This already happened when I've done the 8.1 upgrade from 8. What I had to do was restore a backup I previously made. This is not an option now.

I managed to access the advanced boot menu via the Windows 8.1 installation DVD but I can't seem to do a system restore. When I choose the restore point it seems to do all the process just fine but in the end it gives me error 0x80070057 "An unspecified error occurred during System Restore" Details: System Restore failed to extract the original copy of the directory from the restore point. Source %ProgramFiles%\WindowsApps. Destination: AppxStaging.

I'm guessing there's some permission issue, can I give special permissions to System Restore via cmd?

Refresh/Reset are not viable options, I hope someone can help me because I need to work with this machine but I'm stuck and I'm loosing my mind.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed the [prerequisites](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355)?

Comment: From what I've read from other forums, `AppxStaging` errors are caused by disabled UAC (User Account Control).  You can enable it through regedit, or by searching "UAC" from the start page.