# Black screen after installing Windows 8.1 Update (KB2919355)

Tags: windows-8, drivers, windows-update, nvidia-geforce, intel-graphics

This is quite similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/750351/flickering-black-screen-after-kb2919355-windows-8-1-update-1-no-os-access), which I see has no answers (so I may just be out of luck).

That said, my scenario is slightly different.

This morning, I manually updated to Update 1 using the downloads from Microsoft. The installation was successful, and all the prerequisites were installed. I installed manually for two reasons:

1. I've had issues in the past with updates failing, and then working a second time.
2. Data is expensive, I can't afford for updates to fail and then get re-downloaded (sometimes it's cached, sometimes not).

So, I installed the update, which ran sucessfully. Then, I rebooted, and got the black screen, *without* the cursor (even wen moving the mouse - no cursor flickering as others have experienced). Now, the laptop is a touch-screen. So, I touched it, and BAM, Windows 7 silver loading cursor appeared with the tiny touch screen cross-hairs. And then it was gone.

I thought that it may just be a delay, and so I let it sit for 30 minutes. Nothing.

Some points to note:

1. Safe Mode does not work
2. Low-resolution mode does not work
3. There are no restore points (why did the update not create one?)

I'm able to access the command prompt, of course, which runs in the good ol' Windows 7 basic window style. From there, I can open up `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log`. The only notable entry there is:

```
Upload callback called with file path: C:\WINDOWS\servicing\sqm\PackageChangeEnd_Package_for_KB2919355~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.3.1.14_0_std.sqm
status: 0x0, HTTP Response: 403
```

Now, I think this appears to have been logged when I initially tried using Windows Update. Thing is, it just sat there for a while saying "Downloading..." I also see that `amd64` is mentioned in there. Why would it say that if I'm x64? I'm sure it's a little something I'm missing there.

There's only one thing that I can think of that may have caused this. Yesterday, My Intel HD drivers updated. It seems that the update was corrupt/botched because my games would no longer open. Turns out that there was something wrong with Optimus in that my GeForce 720M wasn't initialising. So I rolled back that update. Problem is, I couldn't roll back from Windows Update. So I re-installed the driver that came packaged with my Lenovo S510P. This is the only thing I believe could be causing this problem. Note: there were two installed updates after the original drivers.

One more note: there seem to be a whole bunch of files pending renames (`C:\Windows\WinSxS\Temp\PendingRenames`), all from yesterday's successful updates (.NET etc). Could this perhaps cause an issue?

Now, please could someone help me with either of the following?

1. Roll-back KB2919355 using the command prompt (no idea how to do this - I may not have entered the correct DISM command. **Edit**: Turns out that won't work when using command prompt; access to `/online` is prohibited.)
2. Alternatively, update the Intel driver to the latest - I don't care about gaming right now; as long as the laptop can start up, I'll be happy.

There may also be other solutions - if there are, please let me know.

Thanks a ton.

### Update

Because I'm impatient and have quite a bit of work to do, I landed up doing a Refresh. Problem is that it reverted back to Windows 8, build 9200. Is that normal? My laptop came with 8.1 pre-installed, and so I would assume that they installed from an 8.1 image... Meh, this day has been way too long.

Comment: `amd64` is the generic reference to everything 64-bit considering the entire `Intel x86` 64-bit extension is based on AMD's work.

Comment: "Problem is that it reverted back to Windows 8, build 9200. Is that normal?" - *Yes* This is normal.  Because this happen its clear you are mistaken about what version of Windows came installed on your system.  This happened because the image used to perform the operation wasn't updated when Windows 8.1 was installed through the Windows Store.

Comment: I thought as much. It's just a little sad that the store I bought the laptop from didn't do so. It's kinda like false advertising. I think they could have put a disclaimer in there somewhere.

Comment: It wasn't the store that is at fault.  It is Microsoft that never made it clear the image should be updated.

Comment: That would make sense. Disappointing, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a system restore to a restore point from before the problems occurred. Press the CTRL+ALT+DEL keys, then go to the power button (usually button on the bottom right) and click Restart **whilst you are holding Shift down**. That gets you into all the recovery options. Go to Advanced Options.

The command prompt command is **rstrui.exe**. But that is less flexible.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but please read the question properly before posting anything. I did state that there are no restore points.

Comment: Sorry Mike, I must have missed that. Btw - it is normal that a refresh sets you back to Win 8 if that's what the machine came with originally. You can avoid that in the future by setting your own refresh recovery images. See here ==> http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9310-refresh-windows-8-set-custom-recovery-image-active.html

Comment: No problem. Yeah, I see that's the case. Now I have to get to a friend with a good unshaped line so I can run all these updates.