# Acrylic DNS Proxy not resolving

Tags: windows-8, dns, apache-http-server, proxy, hosts-file

So I recently had an [update issue](https://superuser.com/questions/895779/black-screen-after-installing-windows-8-1-update-kb2919355) where I landed up downgrading to Windows 8. As I need to do my work, I have re-installed my XAMPP server as well as Acrylic DNS Proxy.

Unfortunately, Acrylic is not working, and I think I may have missed something.

My AcrylicHosts file looks like this:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 *.local
```

Apache is configured correctly, and it does work if I add a manual entry to `hosts`. I turned off the firewall and restarted Acrylic, but that didn't change anything. I've flushed the DNS cache. I've made sure that the Ethernet DNS is set to 127.0.0.1. I did see a suggestion regarding actually having to connect an Ethernet cable to 'activate' it or something, but that didn't work - besides I didn't have to do that when I was using Windows 8.1.

Anything else I can do to get Acrylic working?

Answer (score 1):

Mike I've fixed a bug regarding AAAA queries not resolved properly from the AcrylicHosts.txt file in versions <= 0.9.27.

If you use the latest (0.9.28) version you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks, Massimo - I'll be sure to try it this weekend. :-)